# Learning PowerShell. Create usernames no longer than 8 characters and check for collision

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm learning powershell right now.

I need to import a CSV like this:
lastname,firstname
lastname,firstname
lastname,firstname
etc

Then create a list of usernames no longer then 8 characters and check for collisions.

I have found bits and pieces of scripting around but not sure how to tie it all together.

I use `Import-Csv` to import my `file.csv`:

```
$variablename = import-csv C:\path\to\file.csv
```

but then I am not sure if I just import it into an array or not. I am not familiar with how for loops work in powershell exactly.

Any direction? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to create your usernames? surname+firstname? surname+initial? surname+[first X letters of firstname]?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of concepts that are central to understanding PowerShell. Firstly, remember that you are always working with objects. So after importing your CSV file, your `$variablename` will refer to a collection of sub-objects.

Secondly, you can use the PowerShell pipeline to send the output of one cmdlet to the input of another. Some cmdlets will understand if you send them a collection, and automatically process each row.

If think what you're looking for though is the `foreach-object` cmdlet, which will allow you to run code against each item in the collection. Code inside the `foreach-object` block can refer to the `$_` automatic variable which will contain the current object.

Assuming your CSV file is well formatted and has a header row with the column names, you can refer to each column by name e.g. `$_.lastname` & `$_.firstname`.

To put it all together:

```
import-csv C:\path\to\file.csv | 
    foreach-object {
        write-host "Processing: $($_.lastname), $($_.firstname)"
        # logic here to calculate username and create AD account
    }
```

PowerShell can have a bit of a learning curve if you are coming from a different scripting environment. Here are a couple of resources that I've found helpful:

PowerShell 'gotchas' http://www.rlmueller.net/PSGotchas.htm

Keith Hill's Effective PowerShell: https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/

Also, check out the Technet Script Center, where there are many hundreds of Active Directory scripts. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The script below should help you grasp a few concepts on how to work with csvs and manipulate data using PowerShell.

```
# the code below uses a 'here string' to mimic the import of a csv.
$users = @'
smith,b
smith,bob
smith,bobby
smith,sonny
smithson,john
smithson,jane
smithers,rob
'@ -split "`r*`n"

$users |
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Header 'surname','firstname' |
  Select-Object @{Name='username'; Expression={"$($_.surname)$($_.firstname)        "}}, surname, firstname |
  Group-Object { $_.username.Substring(0,8).Trim() } |
  Select-Object @{Name='username'; Expression={$_.Name}}, Count |
  Format-Table -AutoSize
```

The `$users |` line takes the list of $users and pipes into the next command.

The `ConvertFrom-Csv -Header...` line converts the string into a csv.

The `Select-Object @{Name...` line creates an expression alias, which concatenates surname+forename. You'll notice the extra 8 spaces we append to the end of the string so we know we will have at least 8 characters in the string.

The `Group-Object {...` line groups the username, using the first 8 characters, if available. The `.Trim()` gets rid of any trailing spaces.

The `Select-Object @{Name='username'...` line takes the Name field from the group-object and renames to username and also shows the count from the grouping operation.

The `Format-Table -AutoSize` line is purely for output formatting to the console and gives you an output like the one below.

```
username Count
-------- -----
smithb       1
smithbob     2
smithson     3
smithers     1
```

An amended version of the above code, which you can use on your real csv. Change the surname, firstname column names to suit your csv.

```
# you would use the code below, to import your list of names
# uncomment the `# -Header surname,firstname` bit if your csv has no headers
$users = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\path\to\names.csv' # -Header surname,firstname

$users |
  Select-Object @{Name='username'; Expression={"$($_.surname)$($_.firstname)        "}}, surname, firstname |
  Group-Object { $_.username.Substring(0,8).Trim() } |
  Select-Object @{Name='username'; Expression={$_.Name}}, Count
```